# How to succsessfully compille .cpp files using gcc with out adding -lstdc++ flag?

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++

The autograder of my class uses gcc to grade our projects, it only takes file uploads(.cpp .h), students can't pass in any argument flags.
My project compiles with g++ with no issues:

> g++ main.cpp func1.cpp func2.cpp func1.h -o a.out

but with gcc I have to add -lstdc++ at the end for it to compile:

> gcc main.cpp func1.cpp func2.cpp func1.h -o a.out -lstdc++

otherwise the errors:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cck9qDRT.o: in function main': main.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to std::cout'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<< std::char_traits<char >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*)' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to std::cin'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to std::istream::operator>>(int&)' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to std::cin'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to std::istream::operator>>(int&)' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to std::cout'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(int)' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&)'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to std::cout'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(int)' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&)'
> /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cck9qDRT.o: in function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
> main.cpp:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()' /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTpZnaT.o: in function fib1()': func1.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to std::cout'
> /usr/bin/ld: func1.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<< std::char_traits<char >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*)' /usr/bin/ld: func1.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&)'
> /usr/bin/ld: func1.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTpZnaT.o: in function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
> func1.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()' /usr/bin/ld: func1.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2MzCjT.o: in function fib2()': func2.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to std::cout'
> /usr/bin/ld: func2.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<< std::char_traits<char >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, char const*)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2MzCjT.o: in function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
> func2.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()' /usr/bin/ld: func2.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How do I compile using gcc without needing the -lstdc++?  Does manually including all the standard libraries used on the project in code fix it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The answer, surprisingly, is it can't be done.  According to the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b), the gcc command recognizes `.cpp` files as C++, but *the use of gcc does not add the C++ library*.

From your description, this sounds like a technical error in how the autograder was set up, and everyone in your class will encounter the same difficulty.

> Does manually including all the standard libraries

That way lies madness.  Don't even think of it.